# Ultisnips causes problem with unmapped f-keys in nvim insert mode

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips

With <kbd>F2</kbd> unmapped, for instance, I get a load of error messages (see below).

I realized I can fix this by mapping the f-keys, but I'm curious: are they mapped to something by Ultisnips, that doesn't work?  Or is this a symptom of an underlying problem?

(This happens even with a minimal vimrc, that does nothing but load ultisnips with vim-plug.)

PS.  I think the problem has to do with the fact that in nvim `<f2>` is mapped as if with `imap <f2> <F2>`, which causes a loop (because for some reason, with ultisnips, `<F2>` is interpreted as a key rather than as a string).  This can be confirmed by testing first `imap <f2> <f2` and then `imap <f2> <f2>`. Without ultisnips, the string `<F2>` is inserted without any error messages.

```
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
NvimError(b'Vim(new):E523: Not allowed here: botright new',)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
  File "/Users/lawrence/.config/nvim/plugged/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet_manager.py", line 61, in wrapper
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
  File "/Users/lawrence/.config/nvim/plugged/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet_manager.py", line 829, in _track_change
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
    inserted_char = _vim.eval('v:char')
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
  File "/Users/lawrence/.config/nvim/plugged/ultisnips/pythonx/UltiSnips/_vim.py", line 117, in eval
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
    rv = vim.eval(as_vimencoding(text))
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neovim/api/nvim.py", line 124, in eval
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#TrackChange..provider#python3#Call:
line   18:
    return self._session.request('vim_eval', string, async=async)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: First, you can see what script/plugin sets a map with this command: `:verbose map <F2>`. Also, if you use vim in terminal, maybe F2 is seen as a succession of other keys instead. For example, if I do a `Ctrl-V` `F2` in insert mode in Vim, i get the codes for `Ctrl-[` `OQ` (i.e. `Esc O Q`). Maybe something like that is tickling your Ultisnips.

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was posted in 2016, this was a bug in UltiSnips. This issue was also reported on github [here](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/691), and it has since been fixed in 2017.

(There was a separate, but [related issue](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1202): neovim would freeze when a function key is pressed. In that issue, the solution was to update pynvim.)